# OpenLayers FrameCloud does not find JavaScript functions

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to use a function inside the FrameCloud function:

```
if (selectedFeatures.length > 0) {
                    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "featurePopup",
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy),
                        null,
                        buildSelectTagWithFeatures(),  
                        null,
                        true
                    );

                    map.addPopup(popup);
                }
```

Which then calls buildSelectTagWithFeatures:

```
function buildSelectTagWithFeatures()
            {

                var record;
                var info = "<div class=\"selecttag\">";
                info += "<select id='featureSelect'>";

                // Loop through all objects found
                for (var i = 0 ; i < selectedFeatures.length; i++) {

                    // Setup next object
                    record = selectedFeatures[i];

                    // Setup select option
                    info += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + record[0].Value + "</option>";

                }

                info += "</select>";
                info += "<button onclick='buildSelectedFeature();'>Show</button>";
                info += "</div>";
                info += "<div class=\"selectfeature\"></div>";

                return info;
            }
```

At this point, the user selects a feature from the drop-down and clicks on "Show", at this point the onclick function is suppose to fire.  The funtion buildSelectedFeature() is there but it cannot find it.  In Firefox, it is giving me an error `"ReferenceError: buildSelectedFeature is not defined"`.

Why does it not find the function and how do I get it to find the function?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably down to scoping and/or timing issues. Have you tried setting a breakpoint when your code reaches the popup creation part and then check if the function is available?

On another note: You seem to be a bit shaky in JavaScript, why don't you pass the selectedFeatures array as an argument to buildSelectedFeature, instead of relying on it beeing there in the outer scope?

I'm also rather confident that no matter how much you say that "The funtion buildSelectedFeature() is there", it cannot be available for calling at that point in your code.

Try to rewrite your first code block to:

```
if (selectedFeatures.length > 0) {                    
    var html = buildSelectTagWithFeatures(selectedFeatures);
    console.log(html);
}
```

in order to check that the function actually returns what you want (and is available). The second block should read:

```
function buildSelectTagWithFeatures(selectedFeatures) {

            var record;
            var info = "<div class=\"selecttag\">";
            info += "<select id='featureSelect'>";

            // Loop through all objects found
            for (var i = 0 ; i < selectedFeatures.length; i++) {

                // Setup next object
                record = selectedFeatures[i];

                // Setup select option
                info += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + record[0].Value + "</option>";

            }

            info += "</select>";
            info += "<button onclick='buildSelectedFeature();'>Show</button>";
            info += "</div>";
            info += "<div class=\"selectfeature\"></div>";
            return info;
        }
```

(Notice that it now takes selectedFeatures as a parameter)

If the error still exists, try moving the declaration of the buildSelectTagWithFeatures to somewhere you know makes it reachable by the first block (i.e. right before it)

Comment: Thanks.  Note: It is the second function that cannot be found: buildSelectedFeature(). The buildSelectTagWithFeatures() is found.  Something to do with the FrameCloud...

Comment: I think this might be my issue: https://github.com/jorix/OL-FeaturePopups/issues/6

Comment: Ah, i didn't expect to find an onclick event in there. FYI: onClick should be avoided, and given the state your code is in I cannot really give a better answer than look up jQuery or some other sane frameworks.